# Let $a \in G$ is the generator of the group G.For any integer $m,n$, if gcd(c,m) = n, then $<a^m> = <a^n> $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, finite-groups, proof-writing, cyclic-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite cyclic group with the order $c$, and let $a \in G$
>   is the generator of the group. For any integer $p, q$, if $\gcd(c, p) = q$,
>   then $<a^p> = <a^q> $.

Proof:

Let $G$ be a finite group with the order $c$.
Since $$<a^p> = \{x \in G | x = (a^p)^n, \quad where \quad n \in Z\}$$ and 
$$<a^q> = \{y \in G | y = (a^q)^m, \quad where \quad m \in Z \}$$
, we are going to show that $<a^p> = <a^q>$.

Let $a_0 \in <a^p>$. Since $\gcd(c, p) = q$, there is some $l \in Z$ such that $lq = p$, so $a_0 = (a^p)^n = a^{(q)(nl)}$.

Since $nl \in Z$, $a_0 \in <a^q>$, so $<a^p> \subseteq <a^q>$.

Similarly, $<a^q> \subseteq <a^p>$, and thence $<a^p> = <a^q>$.

---

So my question is, is there any flow in this proof ? or any suggestion about any point in the proof ?

Note: $<a> = \{ x \in G | x=a^n$ where $n \in Z  \}$

Comment: I think you cannot use `similarly` here because you use the fact that $\gcd(c, p) | p$ to conclude $lq = p$ for some $l \in \mathbb{Z}$ but we don't have $\gcd(c, q) = p$. I guess it is better to use Benzout's lemma here, i.e. $\gcd(c, p) = q \implies \exists x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $cx + py = q$.

Comment: Personally, I was able to quickly convince myself that $<a^p> \subseteq <a^q>$. It was the other way around that was interesting to me. However I don't follow your 'similarly' for this part. My advice would be to explicitly prove $<a^q> \subseteq <a^p>$ and potentially drop the other way around as possible to do 'similarly'

Comment: @dimpol, Ok I'm going to try.

Comment: @AlexVong got it, thanks.

Comment: @AlexVong but by using that lemma, we are getting such an expression $a_0 = a^{(cx + py)m}$, which I cannot change into the form $a_o = a^{pr}$ for some $r \in Z$.

Comment: By definition, $c = |G|$. Do you know what is $a^{|G|}$ for any $a \in G$?

Comment: @AlexVong Yes, I know, thanks a lot :)

Comment: [You are welcome](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2877/you-are-welcome-or-you-are-welcomed-or-you-welcome)!